# How to sort the content of text file .txt by files size

Tags: grep, ls, sort

the file has been generated by

```
ls -Raltr -block-size=M /* > /home/root/all_files.txt
```

I have tried several commands with grep to no avail.

Comment: Parsing `ls`, even indirectly, is prone to failing in edge cases (groups with spaces in their name, filenames that have newlines in their name, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `-S` with `ls`, to sort directory contents by size.  Files are still grouped by directory, which might not be what you want:

```
ls -RaltrS --block-size=M /*
```

This approach might not be an option here; perhaps `all_files.txt` is an old file or was generated on a different computer.  It's still possible to sort the filenames by file size.  For a typical file, a line of output produced by `ls -Raltr --block-size=M` (note that `--block-size` starts with two hyphens instead of one) looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner group 1M Apr 16 05:37 file.txt
```

Use `sort` with `-h` (for human-readable numbers such as 1M), and with `-k 5` to specify that the file sizes are in the fifth column (delimited by blank space) of text:

```
sort -k 5 -h /home/root/all_files.txt
```

Sorting the ouput of `ls -Raltr --block-size=M /*` that is stored in `/home/root/all_files.txt` can be messy because of the extra lines that do not list file sizes, so use `grep` first to get only the lines you want:

```
grep '^-' /home/root/all_files.txt | sort -k 5 -h
```

Here, `grep '^-'` discards lines that do not start with a hyphen (eg, lines that start with `d` for directory or `l` for link).

This anwswer works with GNU tools on Xubuntu 16.04.  It has not been tested on MacOS or BSD systems.

Comment: Using `ls`'s sorting option is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

To sort all regular files in or under the current directory by size, the `zsh` shell provides the handy `**` globbing pattern that matches across `/` in pathnames (i.e. "recursively down into subdirectories).  It also allows for *qualifying* a pattern so that you e.g. get only a match of regular files, and that the results are sorted according to the size of these files.

In the `zsh` shell, this pattern would look like

```
**/*(.OL)
```

This would return all regular files (`.`) ordered in reverse (`O`) size order (`L`).

To get the listing of just the files, use

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(.OL)
```

To get `ls` "long listing" output, use

```
ls -fl **/*(.OL)
```

(the `-f` option prevents `ls` from doing its own sorting of the files).

If `zsh` is not your ordinary shell, you can still use these commands, assuming `zsh` is installed on your system:

```
zsh -c 'ls -fl **/*(.OL)'
```

You could obviously also add `--block-size=M` to that if you're using GNU `ls`.

If you are interested in just the ten largest files, use the pattern

```
**/*(.OL[1,10])
```

instead.

Comment: I'm impressed with `zsh`'s globbing features.  Too bad I handle a fleet of servers that includes a lot of legacy systems, so I need to stick to lowest common denominator.